# Implementing YOLO/Tensorflow object detection on Hololens

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, tensorflow, hololens

I'm developing an object detection project on Hololens. Yolo/tensorflow have been the best choice for object detection but they don't have solid support on UWP, which is a bummer. Even unity ML-agents cannot run on UWP devices (correct me if i'm wrong). So, i'm wondering what are the possible solutions to use Yolo/tensorflow on Hololens using unity3d?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Nop, i’m not working on this project anymore

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile Unity has its own inference engine called [Barracuda](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.barracuda@1.0/manual/index.html). You can use it to execute (some) [models in ONNX format](https://github.com/onnx/models).